# Using image in Jquery is not working - Escaping quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hello am a newbie in jquery.

I have a voting system in wordpress

this is bit of code

WOrks fine when

```
$.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data,
    function(response){
        if(response!="-1") {
            el.html("VOTED").unbind("click");
            if(response=="null") {
                alert("A vote has already been registered to this IP address.");
            } else {
                $("#votecounter").html(response);
                alert("Thanks for your vote.");
            }
```

When using Text in

```
el.html("VOTED")
```

But When i am using 
this i am using this its not working

```
el.html("<img width="584" height="455" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Hydrangeas.jpg" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="Hydrangeas">")
```

Comment: I wouldn't give the user information on how to bypass the voting system. Instead of saying "This IP has already voted", simply write "You have already voted".

Comment: Multicolor string highlighting is a sign that something is not right. Before posting a question in SO, check syntax with JSLint, console errors, documentation, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
el.html('<img width="584" height="455" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Hydrangeas.jpg" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="Hydrangeas">')
```

Comment: how do i add class also
after it
el.html()
add.class

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your quotes. The syntax highlighter here on Stack Overflow is even showing the post to have incorrect formatting.

Example:

```
el.html("<img width=\"584\" height=\"455\" src=\"/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Hydrangeas.jpg\" class=\"attachment-large wp-post-image\" alt=\"Hydrangeas\">")
```